# Rasterize() slow on large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, alternatives?

Tags: raster, r-raster, rasterizing, rasterize

I have a large (266,000 elements, 1.7Gb) SpatialPolygonsDataFrame that I am try to convert into 90m resolution RasterLayer (~100,000,000 cells)

The SpatialPolygonsDataFrame has 12 variables of interest to me, thus I intend to make 12 RasterLayers

At the moment, using `rasterize()`, each conversion takes ~2 days. So nearly a month expected for total processing time.

Can anyone suggest a faster process? I think this would be ~10-40x faster in ArcMap, but I want to do it in R to keep things consistent, and it's a fun challenge!

### general code

```
######################################################
### Make Rasters
######################################################
##Make template
r<-raster(res=90,extent(polys_final))

##set up loop
loop_name <- colnames(as.data.frame(polys_final))

for(i in 1:length(loop_name)){
a <-rasterize(polys_final, r, field=i)
writeRaster(a, filename=paste("/Users/PhD_Soils_raster_90m/",loop_name[i],".tif",sep=""), format="GTiff")
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/ecohealthalliance/fasterize

Comment: fasterize() is UNREAL. So much faster than rasterize(). Thank you SO much for sharing, I can't believe the difference

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a case for using GDAL, specifically the [`gdal_rasterize`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html) function.

You probably already have GDAL installed on your machine if you are doing a lot of spatial stuff, and you can run GDAL commands from within R using the `system()` command. I didn't do any tests or anything but this should be be MUCH faster than using the `raster` package in R.

For example, the code below creates a raster from a shapefile of rivers.  This code creates an output file with a 1 value wherever a feature exists, and a 0 where no feature exists.

```
path_2_gdal_function <- "/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/gdal_rasterize"
outRaster <- "/Users/me/Desktop/rasterized.tiff"
inVector <- "/Full/Path/To/file.shp"
theCommand <- sprintf("%s -burn 1 -a_nodata 0 -ts 1000 1000 %s  %s", path_2_gdal_function, inVector, outRaster)
system(theCommand)
```

- the `-ts` argument provides the size of the output raster in pixels
- the `-burn` argument specifies what value to put in the output raster where the features exist
- `-a_nodata` indicates which value to put where no features are found

For your case, you will want to add in the `-a attribute_name` argument, which specifies the name of the attribute in the input vector to be burned into the output raster. Full details on [possible arguments here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html).

Note: that the `sprintf()` function is just used to format the text string that is passted to the command line using the `system()` function

Comment: I keep hearing about the gdal functions but there are so few worked examples that I find them hard to figure out. The arguments are quite different than most the spatial R packages

Comment: yeah....the argument structure is in the style of linux/unix command line utilities.  It is different than R for sure.  See my edited answer for a worked example.

Comment: This works great for me after the `rasterize()`  method just couldn't do it. I had a bunch of files to rasterize with resolutions below 0.05 to fit the resolution and extent of the corresponding raster images. I tried the rasterize method on one of the files, but I couldn't get any results after letting it run the whole night. I tried the new `fasterize()`  function, it wasn't any better. So I tried this method and got results within a minute, and wrote a script to batch rasterize all files, which took about 15 minutes to rasterize 13 files.